# NSDateFormatter dateFromString return wrong year

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have these following snippet.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat : @"yyyy/MM/dd"];
NSString *timeStr = @"2015/05/16";
NSDate *timeDate = [formatter dateFromString:timeStr];
```

But when I print timeDate in console,the output is werid.The year becomes 4003.

```
4003-05-16 16:00:00 +0000
```

I test it in iPad 8.3(12F69)(not simulator).System time zone is Beijing.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry,I want a correct NSDate instance,not just want to print something.Anyway,thanks

Comment: can you please check my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question, but I checked another answer. Sorry....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the `locale` of the formatter. If you want to use gregorian calendar regardless of the device settings, you generally should set locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

```
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

See Apple [Technical Q&A #1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html). This is geared towards RFC 3339/ISO 8601 dates, but it really applies anywhere you're trying to use standard calendar for converting date string for internal purposes (i.e. as opposed to those dates that are presented to the end user in the UI, which generally should use the device's locale).

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Just need to add last line while printing output.

```
NSString *timeStr = @"2015/05/16";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSDate *Date = [formatter dateFromString:timeStr];
NSLog(@"Date =%@", [formatter stringFromDate:Date]);
```